# Best method to transfer/clone large MySQL databases to another server

Tags: backup, mysql, mysqldump

I am running a web application within a shared hosting environment which uses a MYSQL database which is about 3GB large.

For testing purposes I have setup a XAMPP environment on my local macOS machine. To copy the online DB to my local machine I used `mysqldump` on the server and than directly imported the dump file to `mysql`:

```
// Server
$ mysqldump -alv -h127.0.0.3 --default-character-set=utf8 -u dbUser -p'dbPass' --extended-insert dbName > dbDump.sql

// Local machine
$ mysql -h 127.0.0.3 -u dbUser -p'dbPass' dbName < dbDump.sql
```

The only optimization here is the use of `extended-insert`. However the import takes about **10 hours**!

The dumb file already includes commands to disable unique and foreign key checks to speed up the import:

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
```

I am not an SQL export and not sure if the `/*!40014` commands are executed or not, so added `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` manually to the file to make sure the checks are disabled. However this does not make any difference.

**Why does it take so much time to import the data? Is there a better/faster way to do this?**

The server is not the fastest (shared hosting...) but it takes just about 2 minutes to export/dump the data. That exporting (no syntax checks, no parsing, just writing...) is faster than importing (parsing, syntax check, etc.) is not surprising but 300 times faster (10 hours vs. 2 minutes)? This is a huge difference...

Isn't there any other solution that would be faster? Copy the binary DB file instead, for example? Anything would be better than using a text file as transfer medium.

This is not just about transferring the data to another machine for testing purposes. I also create daily backups of the database. If it would be necessary to restore the DB it would be pretty bad if the site is down for 10 hours...

Comment: *not sure if the /\*!40014 commands are executed or not* Executed if server version is 4.00.14 or higher. Read [there](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html). *Is there a better/faster way to do this?* There is a lot of backup methods. Read [there](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-methods.html). Pay attention to 'Making Delimited-Text File Backups' (DB structure must be dumped separately without data).

Answer (score 3):

The slow import is a symptom of a poor configuration on the destination server.

Increase the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 70% of the available RAM.
Set `innodb_log_file_size` to 512M (using [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html) procedure (adjust url to mysql server version)).

During import `SET GLOBAL innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0` and set back to 1 after the import is completed.